# How to get geolocation in C#

Tags: c#

I have written code which give me geo-location of user based on IP Address. but when i have connect my pc with USBModem at that time it show wrong location.

```
string apiKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ipInfoDbKey"];
string url = "http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?ip={0}&key=" + apiKey;
//string url = "http://ipinfodb.com/ip_query.php?ip={0}&timezone=false";
url = String.Format(url, ip);
var result = XDocument.Load(url);
var location = (from x in result.Descendants("Response")
select new LocationInfo
{
     City = (string)x.Element("City"),
     RegionName = (string)x.Element("RegionName"),
     Country = (string)x.Element("CountryName"),
     ZipPostalCode = (string)x.Element("CountryName"),
     Position = new LatLong
     {
          Lat = (float)x.Element("Latitude"),
          Long = (float)x.Element("Longitude")
     }
}).First();
return location;
```

i have done some work around the IpAddress. i have noticed one thing when i will connect any USBModem at that it take Modem IP address instead of my pc.can you please tell me how i can get geolocation when pc is connected to Modem by using PC IPaddress?

Answer (score 2):

You need to work out your external IP address for your existing code to work when you connect via your Modem. Why not call something like http://checkip.dyndns.org and parse the return string?

Something like:

```
var req = new HTTPGet();
req.Request("http://checkip.dyndns.org");
string[] resp = req.ResponseBody.Split(':');
string ip = resp[1];
```

Which should give you your external IP address as a string to feed into your existing code.

You can get HTTPGet from [here](http://goldb.org/httpgetcsharp.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply, Can you please tell me How i should Use 
var req = new HTTPGet() in my mvc3 application because it give me error

Comment: Sorry mate, I didn't realise I'd submitted this without finishing it. You can get HTTPGet from http://www.goldb.org/httpgetcsharp.html

Comment: ya by using this i can get my IP even though i connected with external USB Modem, thanks Richard for proper guiding.